# I am confused with this particular ajax object

Tags: javascript, ajax, object, dom

I recently learned a few ajax methods in jQuery and I stumbled upon this code and I cannot figure out what it's doing.

```
ajax: {
        init: function() {
            app.ajax._ctr = 1;
            app.ajax._preloaded = {};
            app.ajax.inProgress = false;

            app.dom.$body.on('click', 'a:not(.no-ajax):not([hreflang])', function(e) {
                var $a   = $(e.currentTarget);
                var href = $a.attr('href');
                // what is indexOf
                if (href.indexOf('mailto:') < 0
                    && href != '#'
                    && ((href.indexOf(app.baseUrl) >= 0 && href.indexOf(app.baseUrl) <= 7) || href.indexOf('://') < 0)
                    && !$a.parents('.mejs-container').length) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    app.ajax.loadPage(href, true, $a.attr('data-ajax-resolver'));
                }
            });
            // below is load event
            app.dom.$window.on('load', function() {
                app.ajax.currentStateCtr = app.ajax._ctr;
                history.replaceState({ internal: true, ctr: app.ajax._ctr++ }, null, document.URL);
            });
            // below is popstate event
            app.dom.$window.on('popstate', function(e) {
                if (e.originalEvent.state && e.originalEvent.state.internal) {
                    app.ajax.loadPage(location.href, false, null, e.originalEvent.state.ctr < app.ajax.currentStateCtr);
                    app.ajax.currentStateCtr = e.originalEvent.state.ctr;
                }
            });

        }, // end of init

        getResolver: function(resolverName) {
            if (resolverName !== undefined && app.ajax._resolvers[resolverName] !== undefined) {
                return app.ajax._resolvers[resolverName];
            }

            return app.ajax._defaultResolver;
        },
```

I notice that it declares it within an App object with an empty DOM object. I also understand there are a few jQuery events being used here, but I don't understand exactly how the 'popstate' event and the getResolver function is being used with data.

Comment: `popstate` is not a jQuery event.

Comment: Oops, I don't specifically say that it was, however, if you have any insight into how this object works I am all ears. I understand that it's an event reference that fires when active history changes, but I'm a bit clueless about how this works with the object.  @Bergi

Comment: Most of all it seems to be incomplete. What is `app.ajax`?

Comment: app is a declared object containing this ajax object and other literals which then have an init that couples variables to the empty object. It's last literal is a run function that just runs all the inits. [Full Code Here](https://gist.github.com/WillJHaggard/77cf79d723c764d74dd4)

I'm not sure how to briefly explain because I do not fully understand.
@Bergi